# ls -d */ works in some folders and not in others

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, ls

I'm on a remote server which is a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I need to list only directories in this folder called "NewsData"
I found that `ls -d */` is a good command to list folders, however it works in some folders and not in others.

Below is the sample output

```
(venv_p3.5) anjali@momo:/scratche/home/anjali$ ls -d */
archive/  DownloadImages/  fixed/  getNews/  html/  log/  MonumentData/  NewsData/  Pytorch-finetuning/  src/  TestData/  TrainData/  TrainData2/  venv_p3.5/  VGG16FeatureExtraction/
(venv_p3.5) anjali@momo:/scratche/home/anjali$ cd NewsData/
(venv_p3.5) anjali@momo:/scratche/home/anjali/NewsData$ ls -d */
ls: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
(venv_p3.5) anjali@momo:/scratche/home/anjali/NewsData$ ls 
-  A  B  C  cleanData.py  D  E  F  G  getList.py  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  sequentialNumbering.sh  T  U  V  W  Y  Z
```

Why does this happen? how can I fix this?

Comment: Thank you. If you are happy with `--`, OK, if you still have problems on different platforms, please keep in mind that not all shells limit the `*/` expansion to directories only. So if there still is a difference check your shell and `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The directory contains a subdirectory named `-`, so that expansion of `*/` by the shell includes `-/`, which is being misinterpreted as a command option.

You can avoid this by marking the end of options explicitly using `--` i.e.

```
ls -d -- */
```

or by prepending the glob with a path

```
ls -d ./*/
```

Comment: [Filename expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) is done by bash *before* the values are passed to the program. This is why `ls -d */` can expand to `ls -d -/`.

Comment: Thanks @bytesized I have edited the answer to clarify this point

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "\.*"
```

"-d" means just list that directory as I understand it.

Comment: It's worth noting this omits all hidden directories as well as `.` and `..`

Comment: @Wildcard: which glob expansion also does, at least by default